# Can I programmatically rename/delete VSCode workspaces while they're open in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking to create some PowerShell scripts for my dotfiles repo where I spin up development environments and open them in VSCode automatically, this works fine but would like a nice script (`delete_environment.ps1`) to rename/delete them when I've made the environment with the placeholder name i.e. `~/Documents/project_12345`.

I've looked into a couple options:

1. Killing all processes that are using the directory with Handle
2. Using the [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) to create a javascript file that will close the file in VSCode programatically.

Been struggling with the VSCode option as it seems this is built around creating extensions for VSCode (makes sense) but is there any way I could embed the functionality of removing a workspace directory / renaming a workspace directory directly into a powershell script?

Thanks for the help,

Frankie

**Files**

`close_workspace.js`

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

function close_workspace() {
  // Temporary VSCode Command to see if I can get any of them working
  vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.addCommentLine');
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "close_workspace",
    "type": "module",
    "main": "./close_workspace.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.85.0"
    }
}
```

**Execution & Error**

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant\Documents\path-files\js> node .\close_workspace.js
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vscode' imported from C:\Users\vagrant\Documents\path-files\js\close_workspace.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1131:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v21.6.0
```